# Nested jQuery request to go to same location on site

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, nested

I am trying to load two layers of pages using jQuery requests and am getting nowhere. What I want is for the top level page to select content from another page to load into a specific area on the page (named CenterDataBox) and the first request works great. I want a selection on that second page to get more data.

For example, I am loading a list of shows that are scheduled from a file... I get that fine. Within each one of those line items, however, I want to then load - into the SAME container (div block), the content from another page that is specific to that show (host bios, details, etc). So, in effect a nested request. Just placing a hyperlink in that section opens a whole new page (not placing the info into the current container (div tag) as I had hoped when  I used `target="_self"`) so I tried the following to no avail.

Sorry if the code formatted oddly. I am trying to retrieve a click from the `#bob`, which is in `#DN_Vars9` to grab data from `#DN_shows5` and place into into the parent's (index.html)  div tag named `CenterDataBox`... so two layer deep nesting. Getting the info from DN_Vars9 works fine, it's that second step I can't figure out.

I thought of inserting the jQuery load functions into the DN_Vars9 file, which would permit selection, but then I am unsure on how to guarantee that the end result data shows up in the grandparent's container (index.html) 'CenterDataBox' - that might be the easier way to answer this.

Any suggestions? What am I missing here?  The first four lines work, it's that last line that is incorrect.

Thanks!!!!

The code in "DN_Vars9" looks like: Bob

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#HomeBase").click(function() {
        $("#CenterDataBox").load("pages/DN_Vars9.html#FaceBookFeed");
        return false;
    });

    $("#ShowSched").click(function() {
        $("#CenterDataBox").load("pages/DN_Vars9.html#SchedulePage");
        return false;
    });

    $("#AboutLink").click(function() {
        $("#CenterDataBox").load("pages/DN_Vars9.htm #AboutPage");
        return false;
    });

    $("#FAQLink").click(function() {
        $("#CenterDataBox").load("pages/DN_Vars9.html#FAQPage");
        return false;
    });

    $("pages/DN_Vars9.html#bob").click(function() {
        $("#CenterDataBox").load("pages/shows/DN_Shows_5.html#BobPage");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Add information to your question, please, not in comments.

Comment: first you should attach the hashtag to your URL (there is no space between .html and #!)
second: there is no `$("pages/DN_Vars9.html #bob")` DOM element, you cant use jQuery functions on it

Comment: That's right, it didn't work either with a space or no space there, I will edit the code to be clearer, but I need to understand what does work. Thanks